# How to change image url to Image Logo in rich text custom field.?

Tags: formula, image-formula

I need help to understand how to change the URL value to the image logo.

I have a custom field called image URL datatype (RichText), I would like to convert my image URL to an image logo. can you anyone suggest to me.

[image: Image Url]

Answer (score 0):

Use an "img" tag, to view the image in rich text field, Since rich text supports HTML

Something like this :

```
<img alt="alt text" src="https://mymagic-hub.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/organization/logo.default.jpg"></img>
```

Reference link to learn more about Rich text field :

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf.fields_rich_text_area_limitations.htm&language=en_us

Answer (score 0):

Use a formula with an IMAGE() function to output the image on a detail layout.

```
IMAGE("https://mymagic-hub.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/organization/logo.default.jpg", "Image Name")
```

If you already have the url in a field value, you can reference the value as well

```
IMAGE(Image_Url_Field__c, "Image Name")
```